# Creating a new top level Admin User for Ubuntu on WSL

Tags: users, windows-subsystem-for-linux, adduser

#### Swapping standard Ubuntu for win-10 w/ "WSL Ubuntu"

For 5 years I booted to Ubuntu Distros with a GUI desktop, however; this year, my professor has forced me to add Windows to my machine. In the past I would dual boot the two, however, as I am sure most of you are likely to already know, several Linux distros have been made available for use by developers working in "Windows 10" environments", therefore, I decided to set up WSL rather than dual booting.

#### The Status of my Machine's Operating System

So I was setting up WSL, and referring to the docs here [Official Ubuntu page on WSL](https://ubuntu.com/wsl) whenever I had trouble. I couldn't log into Ubuntu for whatever reason, however WSL & Ubuntu seem to be working fine, so I just used the worlds most famous Linux work around, and logged in as root (which required me to set the default user to root). The problem is, I can't get the initial prompt back to enter a username & password, which, from what I understand, is how a new user is properly created for the virtual WSL Ubuntu instance.

#### In-depth Explanation of the Question at Hand

I have never done this, so I don't know what a proper default sudo/admin account should look like on an "Ubuntu Operating System" that runs in a Windows-10-subsystem. Its it necessary that I get the prompt back, or can I set up a new user on my own? If I do set up a new user on my own then, what is the correct way to configure the top-level Admin account (aka Sudo-account) for a WSL instance of Ubuntu.

##### Things about the configuration that are not exactly clear to me include:

1. Should the account be a system account, and should it use an arbitrary name assigned by ubuntu?
2. Should the account have a home directory?
3. Is the sudo-group `admin:sudo` the only group that the top-security-level admin account (aka Sudo-account) needs to be added to, should I make another group with the same name as the Admin account I am creating?

Comment: Also, if you like the full Ubuntu desktop experience, note that Windows 11 will include WSLg  with the ability to run graphical Linux apps (fairly seamlessly, in my understanding).  In the meantime, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68856351/11810933) if you'd like to be able to access a full desktop environment from within WSL through `xrdp` in Windows.

Comment: Quote formatting and code formatting have specific semantic meanings (e.g., screen readers and other such accessibility software can treat them differently). Do not misuse them just for "looks".

Comment: JAY-DEV I completely agree with @muru here, and recommend not getting into an editing war with him or Zanna ;-).  While I understand your desire for formatting, the edits are absolutely clean, concise, and semantically correct.

Comment: The meanings are loose at best, if you don't like it then flag the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The problem is, I can't get the initial prompt back to enter a username & password, which, from what I understand, is how a new user is properly created for the virtual WSL Ubuntu instance.

Right.  The initial user creation is done when the distribution executable (the `.exe` that is installed from the Microsoft Store) is run for the first time.  In the case of Ubuntu, that's typically `ubuntu.exe`, although it can differ depending on if you installed a "named version" in the Store (e.g. Ubuntu 20.04 specifically).  That said, it is entirely possible to create a default user manually (see below).

Let's start with `wsl -l -v` to see what the distribution name is.  It will most likely be just "Ubuntu", but modify the below commands if it is different.

---

##### *The "easy" button*

It's possible to get back to the initial "configuration" state, with the big assumption and caveat that doing so **will erase all data/configuration in the instance** (the virtual filesystem, etc.).  That command is `wsl --unregister Ubuntu`.

After doing that, you should simply be able to re-run "Ubuntu" from the Start Menu, and the distribution will be recreated.  It will then ask you for the default username/password.

---

##### *Running as root, without the need for `sudo`*

A neat trick that you will probably find useful is that WSL can be started with any available user, including `root`, without the need for a password:

```
wsl ~ -u root
```

```
wsl ~ -u fred
```

While you might initially be alarmed by the ability to run root without a password, keep in mind that, even as root, your permissions in WSL can never exceed your Windows user permissions.  That said, please *never* [do this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1354555/1165986).

---

##### *Sidebar:  Your questions*

First, to answer some of your questions:

> Should the account be a system account, and should it use an arbitrary name assigned by Ubuntu?

Not sure what you mean here exactly, but the answer, I believe, is "no".  The default user can be named whatever you like.  I recommend just using your normally preferred user name for convenience.

> Should the account have a home directory?

Yes, and that home directory should be in `/home`, *not* on a Windows mounted drive (e.g. `/mnt/c`).

> Is the sudo-group admin:sudo the only group that the top-security-level admin account (aka Sudo-account) needs to be added to, should I make another group with the same name as the Admin account I am creating?

The default Ubuntu method (both "pure Linux" and "WSL") is to create a group with the same name as the username.  While perhaps not *required*, I would consider that a "best-practice".

---

##### *Creating a new "default" WSL user without reinstalling*

As far as I can tell, the following will create the default user with the same settings that the stock installer/configuration does.  From within Ubuntu:

```
useradd --create-home --user-group --groups  adm,dialout,cdrom,floppy,sudo,audio,dip,video,plugdev,netdev --password "encryptedPassword" username
```

Of course, modifying `username` to be whatever you want.  Since you are already running as root, no need for `sudo` or any trickery there, of course, but other readers without the OP's use-case may need `sudo` or `wsl -u root` (as documented in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1348858/1165986)).

Of course, most of these groups probably aren't strictly necessary under WSL, but who knows - Some apps may expect some of them, and better safe than sorry.  Again, this is the "stock" group list that is provided for the user when created by the Ubuntu/WSL configurator.

See [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/367559/how-to-add-a-user-without-knowing-the-encrypted-form-of-the-password/367569#367569) for how to create the encrypted password.  Specifically (although personally untested for this exact command-line):

```
useradd --create-home --user-group --groups  adm,dialout,cdrom,floppy,sudo,audio,dip,video,plugdev,netdev --password $(read -sp Password: pw ; echo $pw | openssl passwd -1 -stdin) username
```

---

##### *Setting the default WSL user*

"Normally", the WSL distro installer (e.g. `ubuntu.exe`) modifies the Windows Registry with the default user name for the distro.  I recommend a newer method, though.  As root, create a file `/etc/wsl.conf` with the following contents:

```
[user]
default=username
```

Again, of course, substituting your `username`.

For alternative techniques, see [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1566022/1210833) and its various answers.

---

##### *Recommended next steps*

I personally recommend backing up this "ready-to-run" copy of your distribution at this stage.  Again, from PowerShell:

```
wsl --export Ubuntu "2021-08-26 Default Ubuntu 20.04.tar"
```

If you need to spin up a throwaway WSL instance for testing something out without modifying your "daily driver", you can easily `wsl --import` this distribution (calling it something other than just "Ubuntu"), then throw it away with `wsl --unregister`.

Comment: __`1`__***`UP`***__``__ This is a fantastic answer — it demonstrates that you clearly care about the question that you are answering, and the community to which you, I, the question & this answer all belong. If you were to iterate through my Stack Overflow account, you would find that I too thoroughly answer questions in very much the same way. I rarley ask a question, typically I can find a solution when I get stuck using the resources I have at my disposal, but when I have asked questions in the past, not one of them received an answer that was even close to the quality of this answer.

Comment: @JAY-DEV Thanks for the kind words, and glad I could help.  Even without reading some of your answers (which I plan to do), the time you took to format the question for clarity with headings/etc. showed a level of organization and communication skills well above par.  Kind of reminds me of the mandatory "Intro to Communications" class they give before an MBA.  Return kudos to you as well, and welcome to WSL! :-)